# Force ansible to use YUM on ubuntu

Tags: ansible, sonarqube

I have written an ansible playbook to install Sonar but when i try to run it . I found out that it tries to use apt because i am working on Ubuntu and in playbook I have used Yum to install all packages. I would like to ask that how can I force or override ansible config to use Yum? I am getting an error

```
Unsupported parameter for apt
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 options. Either use [yum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html#yum-module) module, or use [package – Generic OS package manager](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html#package-generic-os-package-manager) with *use=yum*.